# VBA Visio move the selection to the specified location on drawing by defining the basepoint

Tags: vba, visio

I would like to move my objects to the specified location. Unfortunately, when using the following code:

```
 vShp.Cells("PinX").Formula = "230mm"
 vShp.Cells("PinY").Formula = "870mm"
```

All of them go to just one place

[image]

I tried to assign some particular shape into it

```
vShp(1).Cells("PinX").Formula = "230mm"
vShp(1).Cells("PinY").Formula = "870mm"
```

But it looks like I was wrong, as

Wrong number arguments on invalid property assignment.

Is there any chance of moving the whole selection to a specific location without collapsing everything in one place?

I want to move just one shape in that location instead of all.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Visio SDK yet? No, I thought not.

Comment: I have no admin rights, so even if I download Viso SDK I cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can't move multiple shapes at the same time!
Please try create group from these selected shapes, move this group and ungroup.

````
rem ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
rem ' select few shapes
rem ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(931), visSelect
rem ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1046), visSelect
rem ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1088), visSelect
' define group shape
Dim gr As Shape
' convert selected shapes to group
Set gr = ActiveWindow.Selection.Group
' deselect all
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
' select group shape
ActiveWindow.Select gr, visSelect
' move the GROUP shape two inches to the right
Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Move 2, 0#
' ungrop
gr.Ungroup```
````

Comment: Hmm, It won't help me for 2 reasons:
- picking up the individual ID, which will change for a different job
- moving items - which in another job can fall in a completely different location.

Comment: In my example, there are shapes with given ids. Other branches have (but that's for sure) where shapes are selected based on a certain criterion